# Is there a way to shift focus on buttons in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows, I could use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to shift focus from button to button, so I could "click" on the desired button without having to use a mouse.

It appears that I can't do the same thing on a Mac, or is there a way to do it that I didn't realize?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is. From *System Preferences*, under *Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, you can enable **Full Keyboard Access**. You can also change this by pressing `Control+F7`.

[image: Full Keyboard Access]

This allows you to tab between UI elements and select them with the `Space` key.

Comment: under Lion this is set by radio button "All controls" (ctrl + F7) or (fn + ctrl + F7)

Comment: @udo Thanks, yeah … it's the same shortcut for prior versions of OS X too.

Comment: any idea why this is not the default setting?

Comment: @user107729 I have no idea. Usually Apple makes almost everything available as a keyboard shortcut—this is also important for accessibility. Why this isn't the case here, I do not know.

Comment: Ohh, this is awesome, thank you!!!! It has brought me a lot of frustration!